# What is blocking a deictic use of 'it' in this example?

Tags: pronouns, deixis

Consider the following exchange:

[1] Q: *Is your name Jane?*
     Aa: *<sup>*</sup>Yes, it's right.*
     Ab: *Yes, that's right.*

Note that [1Aa] is simply not acceptable. It's not just that *that* is preferred to *it*; it's rather that, in Standard English, *it* simply **cannot** be used here.

Why not?

Yes, in the replies [1A], the reference is clearly (supposed to be) deictic rather than anaphoric (see below); and the characteristic usage of 3rd person personal pronouns *he/she/it/they* is anaphoric. But they certainly can function deictically at least sometimes; [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) gives the following example (p. 1469): *Isn't she lovely!* (uttered while looking at someone's baby).

So why is [1Aa] completely unacceptable, rather than just being less favored than [1Ab]?

I am well aware that *Yes, it is* would be completely acceptable... and I do understand why it would be. But [1Aa] is not, and my question is specifically about why it is not.

**Some background on deixis**

[1Ab] is a clear example of deictic use of *that*, very much like the [27ii] example from CGEL (p. 1461):

> [27] i A: *Kim has been falsifying the accounts.* B: *That's
>   terrible.* [anaphoric] 
>       ii A: *Kim
>   has been falsifying the accounts.* B: *That's a lie.*
>   [discourse-deictic]
>
> In [i] A's utterance is the antecedent for B's *that*, which refers to
>   the situation that A has  described. But in [ii] *that* refers to A's
>   speech act, to a linguistic entity in the prior discourse.

Comment: Bah, I used all my votes for the day, so I can't vote up this wonderful question. You have my spiritual +1, however.

Comment: In the context of *Is your name Jane? Yes, **it is,*** the respondent's ***it*** refers to ***your name***. If the reply is *Yes, **that's** right,* it's ***that** "answer"* (the one you put forward as a possibility) which/that is correct. I don't really see anything confusing about the referent of ***it*** there. Pity us older Brits though - we have to deal with much worse stuff, ***innit**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not asking about _Yes, it is_, though. _Yes, it is_ would be completely acceptable (and I do understand why), whereas _Yes, it is right_ is completely unacceptable (and I don't really understand why).

Comment: @DanBron I appreciate the spiritual +1. Thanks!

Comment: @linguisticturn: As I thought I was pointing out, it's really just a matter of whether there's a credible referent for ***it***. Note that ***that*** is more flexible, since it can refer to *that assertion you just made* (or in your example, *that possible answer you suggested*), but you can't do this with ***is*** unless the intended referent has already been framed as, for example, *Is it true **that** your name is X?*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You say 'unless the intended referent has already been framed.' I _think_ that this is equivalent to saying that _it_ can function only anaphorically. But if so, that's not true. Counterexample: suppose you and your friend are looking at a glass tipping over the edge of the table, and you say, _It's gonna fall._ No prior linguistic framing (if I understand what you mean by that) here; the reference is fully deictic. But even apart from this deictic/anaphoric business, here is my question: why, precisely, doesn't [1Q] count as 'proper framing' for the referent of _it_ in [1Aa]?

Comment: I don't follow that. Possible responses to *It's gonna fall!* include both *It is* (***it*** = the thing that's gonna fall), and *It's/That's true* (***it/that*** = the thing you just said). In that particular case we very much favour ***that*** for the second nuance because ***it*** has already been used with a referent that can't actually "be true". But that doesn't arise with, say, *Life's a bitch, it's true* - which could be a single statement from one person, or one statement by him followed by a rejoinder from someone else agreeing with him.

Comment: @linguisticturn I'm not a linguist, but I think that using 'it' in 1Aa would refer to 'name' (vs 'that' referring to the statement in 1Ab) and it is not 'name' that is right but the _fact_ that her name is Jane that is right. As you've said, she could say 'Yes it is Jane' or 'My name is Jane' meaning that her name is Jane but she would not say 'Yes it is right' or 'My name is right'.

Comment: @TonyLinde If the answer were _Yes, it is_, then _your/my name_ would surely be interpreted to be the antecedent of _it_. Indeed, usually _it_ has an antecedent---but not always. So the question is this: the context makes it clear that in [1Aa], _it_ is meant by the answerer to refer to the whole statement; no one would misunderstand the answerer, we would just say it's bad grammar. But what exactly makes it bad grammar, given that there is clearly enough context to fix the referent of _it_, and given that _it_ at least sometimes functions deictically? Why can't it function that way in [1Aa]?

Comment: @FumbleFingers If I understood you correctly, you were saying that in order for _it_ to refer to something, that something---the intended referent of _it_---must already have been framed. So now, in the sentence _It's gonna fall_, _it_ refers to the glass. What framed the glass as the referent of _it_ in that sentence?

Comment: What framed the glass as the referent of *it* in that sentence? *Something earlier in the conversation* (or otherwise contextually obvious). But it isn't a matter of absolute/binary categorisation. Consider *It is so* as a response to *Life's a bitch*. I'd say it's effectively a matter of opinion / intention there as to whether ***it*** refers to ***life***, or to ***that statement***.

Comment: @linguisticturn I see what you mean and I've no idea if it is bad grammar. Could it be that if the phrase referred to contains anything that could act as an antecedent to 'it' then that interpretation takes precedence over 'it' referring to the whole statement. That would certainly seem to be common usage, whether following from some rule of grammar or not.

Comment: @TonyLinde Anything's possible... But it would be nice if someone actually knew what it was... I certainly don't---thus this question! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'Or otherwise contextually obvious'---yes, precisely! Well, arguably, [1Q] _does_ make it contextually obvious that _it_ in [1Aa] should refer to the entire statement; after all, if someone actually replied to [1Q] by [1Aa], we wouldn't be confused as far as what the person meant by [1Aa]; we would just say the person was using bad grammar. So... what, exactly, is it that makes it bad grammar? It's not a lack of context... so what is it then? That's my question, to which I don't have an answer.

Comment: However, "_Is_  your name [really] Jane?" licences "Yes, it's true!" I can only mention idiosyncrasy (as a convenient label rather than a rationale).

Comment: @linguisticturn “in order for it to refer to something, that something---the intended referent of it---must already have been framed” — This seems exactly right to me. The crux is that _it_ just needs to be framed to function anaphorically; it doesn’t necessarily have to be **linguistically** framed. Non-linguistic context and clues can create enough framing that anaphora works. If you’re both looking at the same glass, and you both know the other is looking at it too, that frames the glass for anaphoric use. In the same situation you could also say, “The glass is going to fall” because →

Comment: → you’ve both contextually framed the glass. If you weren’t both looking at a glass about to fall, neither anaphoric _it_ nor the definite article would be possible there; you’d be left with a recipient wondering what’s going to fall / which glass is going to fall. If you ask, “Is your name Jane?”, the only entity framed for anaphoric use is _(your) name_, so that’s what _it_ would refer to. I disagree with CGEL that “Isn’t she lovely!” is actually a deictic usage—it is anaphoric (or discourse-deictic if you will, but at an even higher level), with the anaphor being metalinguistically defined.

Comment: Filling in the ellipses in the answers as much as possible makes the problem clearer to me, but not the solution. Q: "*Is your name Jane?*" Aa: "*Yes, it [the name that you just said] is [the] right [name].*" Ab1: "Yes, that [name you just said] is [the] right [name]*." Ab2: "Yes, that [statement you just made] is right.*" Here, both Ab1 and Ab2 sound possible to me, but Aa still sounds wrong or at least awkward. But I'm not sure why—maybe because we need a parenthetical explanation of the "it"? There doesn't seem to be a way to make the statement explicit without one.

Answer (score 1):

I think "1Aa" is unacceptable on a semantical point of view. It seems awkward to refer to someone's name as being 'right'. In this sentence, the grammatical function of ' Right ' plays the role of a subject attribute, making an improper judgment of value about someone's given name on a right or wrong standpoint. On the other hand, the sentence '1Ab" refers back to 'that'. I personally never understand what that means whenever 'that' is the subject of a sentence. It just seems unclear. Ultimately, 'that' does not tango with 'it' but pairs with 'this'. There is nothing right or wrong about the name Jane. It's as beautiful as mine, yours, this or that name.

Answer (score 1):

Because the thing that's right isn't the name but the assertion. <*That* her name is Jane> is right/correct. A name alone can't be right or wrong (see 
Robbie Goodwin's answer), but the relation of a name to an individual can be. "That" is a [pro-sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-sentence).

"Yes, it is [Jane]" is correct because it affirms that her name "is Jane", not that her name "is right".

Answer (score 0):

'Right’ and ‘true’ aren’t as interchangeable as they first appear.

I’m sorry I’m off sick without the energy or will-power to expand this and won’t changing ‘right’ in both answers into ‘true’ make both acceptable?

I think the change leaves ‘that’ preferable but also makes ‘Yes, it’s true…’ an option rather than an obvious error.

Comment: I agree that _Yes, it's true_ is not completely unacceptable. Nevertheless, I think that it would be kind of odd-sounding in this context. In order for it to be a likely answer, the context would probably have to be some sort of admitting (as [ComGEL](https://www.amazon.com/Comprehensive-Grammar-English-Language-General/dp/0582517346) says (p. 1115), it 'may' have 'a concessive force'). An example: Q: _I heard she named her baby... 'Apple'?_ A: _Yes, it's true..._ Indeed, if _Is your name Jane?_ were answered by _Yes, it's true_, I'd assume this was an attempt at mild humor.

Comment: So long as you recognize 'Yes, it's true' is quite different from ' Yes, it's right…'

To me 'I heard she named her baby... 'Apple'? A: Yes, it's true... ' is too far off the point to consider.

if 'Is your name Jane?' were answered by 'Yes, it's true', I'd be lost as to why that might be an attempt at mild humour.

Comment: The point, I agree, is what an acceptable answer to _Is your name Jane?_ is. The answer _Yes, it's true_ is more-or-less acceptable, while _Yes, it's right_ is definitely not. One way to rephrase my original question is: is there a _grammatical_ reason _why_ one is acceptable, while the other is not?

Comment: There might not be. It could be, for example, that _that's right_ should actually be considered an idiom, a remnant of times past when grammar worked differently... There is some evidence for this. It sounds awkward to say _the statement that 1+1=2 is right_; we would rather say _is true_ or _is correct_. The _is right_ makes it sound as if there were some doubt as to whether the statement was indeed correct.